# What is to_regclass argument data type in version 9.6?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.6

I use this piece for check  table existing in   version `9.5` and it   works fine:

```
do $$
declare v text;
begin
    SELECT to_regclass(('some'||'table')::cstring) into v;
    raise notice '%', v;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

Now I work with another (remote) database with version `9.6` and this code yields   error:

> function to_regclass(cstring) does not exist

So, what is argument data type for `to_regclass()` function in postgres 9.6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres 9.6 the argument of `to_regclass()` is `text` (in earlier versions it is `cstring`).

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-6.html)

> Make the to_reg*() functions accept type text not cstring (Petr Korobeinikov)
>
> This avoids the need to write an explicit cast in most cases where the argument is not a simple literal constant.

A simple cast of a text expression to regclass should work in both versions:

```
SELECT ('some'||'table')::regclass into v;
```